# Publicar varios proyectos en un mismo servidor con laravel sin cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, servidor

Tengo que publicar varios proyectos hechos en laravel en un mismo servidor contratado que no posee cpanel.

Se necesitan que cada proyecto pueda accederse mediante un puerto, por ejemplo:

```
proyecto1 -> 192.168.9.1:8001
proyecto2 -> 192.168.9.1:8002
proyecto3 -> 192.168.9.1:8003
...etc
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: es muy facil con apache proxy y los puedes poner en varias urls por ejemplo proyecto protecto1.com protecto2.com protecto3.com o como carpetas localhost/1 localhost/2 localhost/3 etc. tambien tengo entendido que se puede con nginx pero yo prefiero apache,  debes acceder por ssh y generar todo desde la terminal si es linux, pero si es windows se puede acceder por servicio de escritorio remoto.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas hacer hosts virtuales. Te pongo el ejemplo con nginx. Tú quieres hacer tres vhosts que escuchan en la misma IP pero distinto puerto.

```
server {
    listen   8001;
    root /ruta/al/proyecto1/;
    #location
}

server {
    listen   8002;
    root /ruta/al/proyecto2/;
    # location
}

server {
    listen   8003;
    root /ruta/al/proyecto3/;
    # location
}
```

No necesitas poner la IP ahí. Si el webserver corre en la máquina `192.168.9.1` responderá las peticiones a esa IP y listo.

En donde dice `location`, como es Laravel, pondrías la cofiguración para servir tu aplicación ya sea con PHP-FPM o con Octane. Lo siguiente es esólo un ejemplo:

**PHP-FPM**

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME     $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
```

**Octane**

```
location / {
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
  proxy_set_header   Connection "";
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_pass                   http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```